# Why is this method invocation ambiguous?

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-7.2

Why does the first call to `Foo` below compile but the second one results in an ambiguous invocation compiler error?

(using c# 7.2)

```cs
    private static void AmbiguousAsyncOverload() {
      Foo(() => Bar());  // This is OK
      //Foo(Bar);        // Error, ambiguous overload
    }

    private static void Foo(Func<int> func) {
      func();
    }

    private static void Foo(Func<string> func) {
      func();
    }

    private static int Bar() {
      return 4;
    }
```

If I remove the first (`Func<int>`) implementation of `Foo`, and hence the possibility of ambiguity, then the compiler (correctly) reports that `Bar` doesn't have the correct signature to be passed into `Foo`, which implies it has enough information to resolve the ambiguity.

I would understand if the compiler didn't look at return values during overload resolution and therefore both calls failed, but my question is why does one call compile ok while the other doesn't.

Comment: @DavidG https://dotnetfiddle.net/iztplI

Comment: @DavidG I can only reproduce it on c# 7.2

Comment: However, try.dot.net does not report an ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, this is only an issue for 7.2 (or older), not 7.3 as the question implies. @eoin Can you confirm your compiler version please?

Comment: This issue was fixed in C# 7.3 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3#improved-overload-candidates)

Comment: @DavidG I assume you're right, but I can't confirm compiler version. I'm using dotnet cli version 2.1.403. If I add `#error version` to the source I get 2.9.0.63127. I can confirm that other new 7.3 features don't compile, which is why I assume you're correct. Apologies I can't confirm this.

Comment: Check the project file, for example if you have `<LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>` then you will be using 7.3.

Comment: I don't have any `<LangVersion>` tag in the project file.

Comment: If <LangVersion> is not specified, the C# compiler will use the latest version it can for the target version of .NET. For .NET Core 2.1 and 2.2, this is C# 7.3. You can check this for your installed compiler by running `csc -langversion:?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/26077) for all versions of C# up until it was fixed in v7.3. Return types were not taken into account during overload resolution. From the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3#improved-overload-candidates) (or the [language proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.3/improved-overload-candidates)) for C# 7.3:

> 3. For a method group conversion, candidate methods whose return type doesn't match up with the delegate's return type are removed from the set.